# Как в for цикле подставлять входные данные? Java

Tags: java, циклы

Всем привет.
Есть вот такой код.
Загвоздка в том месте, где я оставил XXXXXXXX.

Как мне туда каждый раз в цикле подставлять по очереди входные данные ( с 0-го по последний, один цикл).

```
public void MenuText (String ExpectedMenuItem1, String ExpectedMenuItem2, String ExpectedMenuItem3, String ExpectedMenuItem4, String ExpectedMenuItem5){

    List<WebElement> allLi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'navbar_item']/li"));
    int sizeAllLi = allLi.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeAllLi; i++) {               
        Assert.assertEquals(XXXXXXXX, allLi.get(i).getText());
    }
```

Заранее спасибо.

UPD:
Спасибо за советы и за идею использовать переменное число аргументов.  А как мне тогда в этот метод засунуть данные? Так понимаю, это должен быть массив. Это код под Selenium и я хочу использовать TestNG. Входные данные указываю в xml файле. Пока получается так (учитывая ваши советы):

```
@Test
@Parameters({"ExpectedMenuItem1", "ExpectedMenuItem2", "ExpectedMenuItem3", "ExpectedMenuItem4", "ExpectedMenuItem5"})
public void MenuText (String ... expectedMenuItems) {
    driver.get("https://www.medimpact.com/");
    List<WebElement> allLi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'navbar_item']/li"));
    int sizeAllLi = allLi.size();

    for(int i = 0; i < sizeAllLi; i++) {
        // Assert.assertEquals(ExpectedMenuItem, allLi.get(i).getText());
        Assert.assertTrue(expectedMenuItems.length > i);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedMenuItems[i], allLi.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```

Comment: может имеет смысл передавать в метод всё же массив (или список) пунктов меню, а не отдельно. А если их количество внезапно вырастет до 20? Соответственно достаточно будет также по индексу брать из массива.......

Comment: Добавлю ещё, что есть использовать varargs, то не придётся менять внешний код. Примерно так: `public void MenuText(String... ExpectedMenuItems)`

Answer (score 0):

В методе нужно использовать `varargs`. Вот так: `MenuText(String... yourVars)`. Внутри метода ты получаешь массив переменной длины в зависимости от того сколько переменных было передано. Ну а потом уже проходишь его циклом и подставляешь значения.

Answer (score -1):

```
public void MenuText (String ... expectedMenuItems) {
    List<WebElement> allLi = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//ul[@class = 'navbar_item']/li"));
    int sizeAllLi = allLi.size();
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeAllLi; i++) {
        Assert.isTrue(expectedMenuItems.length > i);
        Assert.assertEquals(expectedMenuItems[i], allLi.get(i).getText());
    }
}
```